# How do you upload a blob base64 string to google cloud storage using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, google-cloud-storage

I'm building an application that will allow me to take a picture from my react app which accesses the web cam, then I need to upload the image to google cloud storage using a Hapi node.js server. The problem I'm encountering is that the react app snaps a picture and gives me this blob string (I actually don't even know if that's what it's called) But the string is very large and looks like this (I've shortened it due to it's really large size:

```
"imageBlob": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/...
```

I'm finding it hard to find resources that show me how to do this exactly, I need to upload that blob file and save it to a google cloud storage bucket.

I have this in my app so-far:

```
Item.postImageToStorage = async (request, h) => {
  const image = request.payload.imageBlob;
  const projectId = 'my-project-id'
  const keyFilename = 'path-to-my-file'
  const gc = new Storage({
    projectId: projectId,
    keyFilename: keyFilename
  })

  const bucket = gc.bucket('my-bucket.appspot.com/securityCam');
  const blob = bucket.file(image);
  const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();
  blobStream.on('error', err => {
    h.response({
      success: false,
      error: err.message || '=-->' + err
    })
  });
  console.log('===---> ', 'no errors::::')

  blobStream.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('done::::::', `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`)
    // The public URL can be used to directly access the file via HTTP.
    const publicUrl = format(
      `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`
    );
  });
  console.log('===---> ', 'past finish::::')
  blobStream.end(image);
  console.log('===---> ', 'at end::::')
  return h.response({
    success: true,
  })
  // Utils.postRequestor(path, payload, headers, timeout)
}
```

I ge to the success message/response `h.response` but no console logs appear except the ones outside of the blobStream.on I see all that start with ===--->  but nothing else.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the highest level, let us assume you want to write into file `my-file.dat` that is to live in bucket `my-bucket/my-folder`. Let us assume that the data you want to write is a binary chunk of data that is stored in a JavaScript Buffer object referenced by a variable called `my_data`. We would then want to code something similar to :

```
const bucket = gc.bucket('my-bucket/my-folder');
const my_file = bucket.file('my-file.dat');      
const my_stream = my_file.createWriteStream();
my_stream.write(my_data);
my_stream.end();
```

In your example, something looks *fishy* with the value you are passing in as the file name in the line:

```
const blob = bucket.file(image);
```

I'm almost imagining you are thinking you are passing in the content of the file rather than the name of the file.

Also realize that your JavaScript object field called "imageBlob" will be a String. It may be that it indeed what you want to save but I can also imagine that what you want to save is binary data corresponding to your webcam image.  In which case you will have to decode the string to a binary Buffer. This looks like it will be extracting the string data starting `data:image/jpeg;base64,` and then creating a Buffer from that by treating the string as Base64 encoded binary.

Edit: fixed typo

Comment: Thank you Kolban! That seems to be a fair assumption, I've never worked with this type of data in past experiences. So I was in fact assuming that the .file() took in an actual file not the file name, I guess the confusion was in part also that I don't have a filename begin with, just the base64 string that my front-end generated. 

While this example you've given me worked great, when I download the file that was uploaded, I get an error saying the file has become corrupt. I will update my question with what I tried. Thanks again!

Comment: Howdy ... the great thing about Stackoverflow is that questions are free.  I personally don't think it to be a good idea to dramatically change questions after they are asked unless it is to clarify the question.  In our first puzzle, I think we found a concept of file names vs file content and that (I think) was the core of the question.  We have now transitioned to (what I believe to be) a very distinct different puzzle.  The answer I had a go at working on now no longer matches the question.  What I'd suggest is to restore the original question and maybe create a new question on the current

Comment: Thanks again Kolban, in my haste I went against the common thought on posting in SO. Changed it back.

Comment: No problems my friend.  In the heat of puzzle solving battle we all (at least I do) get excited and our heads full of new notions.   We are all friends here and any questions you raise that I can maybe assist, I'll be sure and jump in.